# How can I listen when a text area on my website is focused using chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am developing a chrome extension, in which whenever I focus on the textarea, of a website, the background script should listen for that and send a message to the content script, which in turn will use innerHtml property to update the text inside textarea.

I am using manifest v3.
Here is my manifest.json file.

```
{
  "name": "Chrome extension",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "author": "Ayush kumar",
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html",
    "default_title": "Chrome extension"
  },
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'; script-src-elem 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://cdn.auth0.com/js/auth0-spa-js/1.2/auth0-spa-js.production.js;"
  },
  "permissions": ["storage", "cookies", "scripting", "activeTab"],
  "host_permissions": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
}
```

Here is the code which I ran

```
 document
   .querySelector("textarea")
   .addEventListener("focus", getForegroundTabId);
```

The error which I see is

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: document is not defined

Uncaught ReferenceError: document is not defined

Error handling response: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')
```

Comment: use "onfocus" attribute on the textarea element.

Comment: The background script can't listen for focus changes, because it can't directly access the websites displayed in the browser, hence your error message. And please don't bold random words, it makes your question look like a speech bubble from an American superhero comic.

Comment: I the google docs, it says that you can use jsdom to emulate a typical browser environment. Here is the [link](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/migrating_to_service_workers/#documents)

Comment: Please tell me why you use background.
I think that it can be completed within the site injected with the content script.

Comment: Look, this is a project, where I want to know what the user is typing in the text area, so I can use machine learning algorithms to autocomplete the text. The content script is only loaded when I open the extension. How can I know what user is typing in the textarea, without the extension being opened every minute.